# search strings list

Tags: c#

Buenas , alguien me podria ayudar porfa o dar una idea de como resolver el siguiente problema

tengo un string en la lista frase "CASA", necesito recorrer la lista de letras y formar
la palabra CASA  es decir el string que este en la lista frase

Comment: agrega tu codigo  no agrege una imagen, teniendo el codigo te podria ayudar mejor.

Comment: La verdad es que no se entiende demasiado bien lo que pretendes hacer. Deberías ampliar la explicación a parte de añadir el código como texto, como te comenta @3lmo, para facilitar el trabajo a quien trate de ayudarte

Comment: bueno lo que yo entendi es que ella intenta buscar en  "letras"  cada letra de "CASA" y despues imprimila, un tipo  filtro para buscar las letras " C - A -A-S-A", cierto?

Comment: 3lmo , exactamente si :D buscar las letras C - A- S - A , el inconveniente es que cada letra esta en una posicion diferente

Answer (score 1):

Para seleccionar en una lista de letras las letras que existen en una cadena puedes utilizar el método de extensión `Where` de LINQ:

```
var frase = "CASA";

var letras = new List<string>
    {"C", "X", "A", "Y", "H", "S", "A"};
var letrasEncontradas = letras.Where(l => frase.Contains(l));

Debug.WriteLine(String.Join("", letrasEncontradas));
```

Si quieres comprobar si todas las letras de `frase` están en `letrasEncontradas` puedes utilizar también LINQ:

```
var frase = "CASA";

var letras = new List<string>
    {"C", "X", "A", "Y", "H", "S", "A"};
// Selecciona las letras que están en frase
var letrasEncontradas = letras.Where(l => frase.Contains(l)).ToList();
// Comprueba si todas las letras de frase están en letrasEncontradas
bool todasEncontradas = frase.All(x => letrasEncontradas.Any(l => l == x.ToString()));

Debug.WriteLine(String.Join("", letrasEncontradas));
// Si no se han encontrado todas se muestra un mensaje indicándolo
if (!todasEncontradas)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Se encontraron {letrasEncontradas.Count()} letras, pero no se encontraron todas.");
}
```

Comment: asier villanueva , gracias ya estoy probando , una pregunta si yo en ves de CASA escribo la frase ROSA que ocurriría ?

Comment: Devolvería las letras de la lista que están contenidas en la frase `ROSA`: `"A", "S" y "A"`..

Comment: oye ahy forma de que las letras encontradas no  se repitan y que devuelva el mismo valor de la frase

Comment: Creo que lo mejor sería que editaras la pregunta y pusieras unos ejemplos de datos de entrada y qué resultado esperas obtener para que tengamos más claro lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacer algo asi :

```html
        
   string []stringToCheck = {"C","A","S","A"};
  string[] stringArray = { "W", "C", "A", "S","A" };
  foreach (string x in stringArray)
{
    if (stringToCheck.Contains(x))
    {
        // Process...
    }
}
```

Fuente de la respuesta : [Stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array)

igualmente puedes ver el metodo find de c# : [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw84x8be(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: oye 3lmo pero si string []stringToCheck = {"CASA"}; es que debe ir en una unica posicion la palabra casa , las letras si en diferentes posiciones

Comment: UPDATE: Quiza esta buscando una mejor solucion, este es un ejemplo de como lo podrias hacer mas facil.

Comment: vale igualmente gracias voy a probar

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer una lista que contenga las letras del abecedario después recorrerla con un foreach.

También tendrías que recorrer la frase requerida por el usuario .

Luego solo tienes que comprobar si las letras coinciden y de ser así imprime.No tendrás que preocuparte por el orden porque el recorrido mismo se lo da.

```
*List<string> Frase = new List<string>();
            Frase.Add("a");
            Frase.Add("b");
            Frase.Add("c");
            Frase.Add("d");
            Frase.Add("e");
            Frase.Add("s");

            string fraserequerida = Console.ReadLine();
            foreach (char b in fraserequerida)
            {
                foreach (string a in Frase)
            {
             
                if (a == b.ToString())
                {
                        Console.WriteLine(a + "-");
                }
                  }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();*
```

Nota:Esta solución es un poco lenta debido al anidamiento de foreach.